# SDK update site for Google Maps for Work not working

Tags: android, xml, google-maps

According to [docs](https://developers.google.com/maps/premium/previous-licenses/mobile/previous-mobile-sdk-android) of Google Maps Platform, the SDK update site is this [XML](https://dl.google.com/geosdk/android-m4b-addon.xml). The XML used to work, but it seems not working recently.

IntelliJ IDEA 2018.2.4 complains "cvc-elt.1.a: Cannot find the declaration of element 'sdk:sdk-addon'".

Chrome has an error on the XML too, "error on line 251 at column 24: xmlParseEntityRef: no name".

How do I fix the error?